# How to paste output data of multiple rows and merge to data frame in R

Tags: r

I have data in the form of

```
> unique(`Lighting fixtures1`$`Organization name`)
[1] "ConEd - Electric"  "National Grid - Electric"  "Central Hudson - Electric"    "RG&E - Electric"             
[5] "NYSEG - Electric"  "Orange & Rockland - Electric" "PSEG Long Island"             "NYSEG - Gas"                 
[9] "RG&E - Gas"                  
> unique(`Lighting controls1`$`Organization name`)
[1] "ConEd - Electric"             "National Grid - Electric"     "Central Hudson - Electric"    "RG&E - Electric"             
[5] "NYSEG - Electric"             "Orange & Rockland - Electric" "PSEG Long Island"             "NYSEG - Gas"                 
[9] "RG&E - Gas"
```

I want in two rows as

```
Row 1: ConEd - Electric, National Grid - Electric,Central Hudson - Electric,RG&E - Electric,          
NYSEG - Electric,Orange & Rockland - Electric,PSEG Long Island,NYSEG - Gas


Row 2: ConEd - Electric,National Grid - Electric,Central Hudson - Electric,RG&E - Electric,
NYSEG - Electric,Orange & Rockland - Electric" "PSEG Long Island,NYSEG - Gas,RG&E - Gas               
RG&E - Gas
```

Answer (score 0):

We may extract the column from both the datasets into a `list`, loop over the `list` with `sapply`, get the `unique` and `paste` (`toString`) the elements together and wrap with `data.frame`

```
data.frame(Col1 = sapply(list(`Lighting fixtures1`$`Organization name`, 
  `Lighting controls1`$`Organization name`), function(x) toString(unique(x))))
```

Answer (score 0):

c(paste(unlist(unique(`Lighting fixtures1`$`Organization name`)), collapse =", "),
paste(unlist(unique(`Lighting controls1`$`Organization name`)),collapse=", "))